# Obtaining rotation and translation matrix of two 3D points

Tags: opencv, 3d, rotation, translation, kinect

I'm using two Microsoft Kinects RGB-D Cameras, which give the depth (z coordinate) in addition to x and y coordinate.

Left Kinect detects the corner of a book at P1 = (25, 43, 19) in its coordinate frame.

Right Kinect detects the same corner at P2 = (63, 22, 10) in its coordinate frame.

How do I find the rotation and translation matrix between these two points? Do I need to convert these points into a world coordinate first? If so, how?

Or can I just do a  rigid body transformation where P2 = R*P1 + T and solving for R and T (Rotation and Translation Matrix)?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is your objective?  It is easy enough to rotate and or translate those two (1x3) matrices.  But what output do you want to gather from the input?